# Bootstrap-Wizard | class="active" added to wrong element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

I use Bootstrap 4.5.0 and am trying to use [this](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) Bootstrap form-wizard (version 1.4.2).

To navigate through the different tabs, the JS should add a *class="active"* attribute to the current step's `<li>`-element. Instead - for some reason that I haven't been able to figure out - it adds the attribute to the `<li>`-element's child element `<a>`. 
This results in the nav-pills not being styled right and the previous/next buttons not working properly.
I manually added/removed the required attributes using Chrome browser's developer tools and confirmed that apparently, everything would work out fine, if the *class="active"* attribute got attached to the `<li>`-element.

Any ideas why the class is added to the wrong element and how to prevent it?

Here's my HTML mark-up:

```
<div id="rootWizard">
    <div class="form-bootstrapWizard">
        <ul class="bootstrapWizard form-wizard">
            <li data-target="#step1" class="active">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> 
                    <span class="step">1</span>
                    <span class="title">Title of Step 1</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#step2">
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> 
                    <span class="step">2</span>
                    <span class="title">Title of Step 2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#step3">
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="step">3</span> 
                    <span class="title">Title of Step 3</span> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#step4">
                <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"> 
                    <span class="step">4</span> 
                    <span class="title">Title of Step 4</span> 
                </a>
            </li> 
            <li data-target="#step5">
                <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"> 
                    <span class="step">5</span> 
                    <span class="title">Title of Step 5</span> 
                </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

This is how I initialize the wizard within the document.ready()-function:

```
$('#rootWizard').bootstrapWizard({
    tabClass: 'bootstrapWizard'

});
```

Comment: That library said it works with bootstrap 3.x, and you are using 4.x.  Still, not likely the problem.  I don't see your content areas. You've also added an additional layer of divs between the rootWizard and the ul class which may be causing you an issue (.form-bootstrapWizard).  You also attached a lot more classes to the different elements, which may or may not be an issue.  Try posting a functioning sample.

Comment: Also it's listed as a bug that the library does not work with bootstrap > 3.3.0: https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/issues/112